# Prove $\sin^{-1}(1)\geq \int_0^b1/\sqrt{1-x^2}dx +(1-b)\pi/2$ for $b \in [0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, inequality, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following inequality:

$$\sin^{-1}(1)\geq\int_0^b1/\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx +(1-b)\pi/2$$

for every $b \in [0,1)$.

I'm given $\sin^{-1}(1) = \pi/2$ and $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is strictly increasing. We also know $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of the strictly increasing function $\sin(x)$ (when $x\in [-\pi/2, \pi/2] $).

**My Attempt**

I can prove using integration and the FTC that 
 $\int_0^b1/\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = \sin^{-1}(b)$.

This information simplifies the inequality to $0 \geq \sin^{-1}(b) - b\times \pi/2$.

I'm having trouble showing that $ \sin^{-1}(b) \leq b\times \pi/2$ given that everything above is true.

Comment: Small thing: it should be $\le$ not $<$ because of $b=0$.

Comment: It should be $\geq$ in the title and $\arcsin(b) \leq b\times \pi/2$ in the body if $b \in [0,\frac{\pi}2)$

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you want to prove is
$$
\arcsin1-\arcsin b<\frac{\pi}{2}(1-b).
$$
This inequality is false for $b$ close to $1$. Indeed, by the Mean Value Theorem
$$
\arcsin1-\arcsin b=\frac{1-b}{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}},\quad b<\xi<1.
$$
If
$$
\frac{1-b}{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}<\frac{\pi}{2}(1-b),
$$
then
$$
b<\xi<\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{\pi^2}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality you seek to prove is not true. Put $b=1/4$.

However, $\sin^{-1}b\le b\pi/2,\ \forall b\in[0,1)$

Let $f(x)=x\pi/2-\sin^{-1}x, f(0)=f(1)=0$

$f'(x)=\pi/2-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$f'(x)>0,\ \forall x\in\Big[0,\sqrt{1-\frac4{\pi^2}}\Big)$ and $f'(x)<0,\ \forall x\in\Big(\sqrt{1-\frac4{\pi^2}},1\Big)$

This means that $f(x)$ initally increases from $f(0)$ to a maxima and then decreases to $f(1)$ in $[0,1]$. So $f(x)$ stays above $\min\{f(0),f(1)\}=0$.
This means $f(x)\ge0\ \forall x\in[0,1)\implies f(b)\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

I think $$\sin^{-1}(b) \leq b\frac{\pi}2$$ for every $b \in \big[0,1)$ since the graph of $y=b$ when scaled upto $y=\frac{\pi}2b\ $ will get above that of  $\sin^{-1}(b)$ for $b\in\big(0,1)$ and equal for $b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is strictly convex on $[0,1],$ then $(b,f(b))$ lies below the line through $(0,f(0))$ and $(1,f(1))$ for $b\in (0,1).$  This implies

$$\frac{f(1)-f(b)}{1-b} > \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1}$$

for $b\in (0,1).$ Apply this with $f(b)=\arcsin b.$

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is reversed.  The correct inequality is
$$\arcsin(1)\geq \int_0^b\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\text{d}x+\frac{\pi}{2}\,(1-b)$$
for all $b\in[0,1]$.  The equality holds if and only if $b=0$ or $b=1$.

As you did, we can show that the inequality above is equivalent to 
$$\arcsin(b)\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\,b$$
for all $b\in[0,1]$.  Now, the function $f:=\arcsin$ is convex on $[0,1]$.  Therefore, for each $b\in [0,1]$,
$$f(b)=f\big((1-b)\cdot 0+b\cdot 1\big)\leq (1-b)\cdot f(0)+b\cdot f(1)$$
by Jensen's Inequality.  This shows that
$$\arcsin(b)\leq (1-b)\cdot 0+b\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}\,b\text{ for all }b\in[0,1]\,.$$
Since $\arcsin$ is strictly convex, the only equality cases are $b=0$ and $b=1$.